# QuickSort algorithm explanation

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

Well, i know this is kind of an odd question, but i found this java code for the quicksort algorithm:

```
private static void quickSort (ArrayList <String> list, int first, int last){

        int g = first; 
        int h = last;

        int midIndex = (first + last) / 2;
        String dividingValue = list.get(midIndex);

        do{
            while (list.get(g).compareTo(dividingValue) < 0) g++;
            while (list.get(h).compareTo(dividingValue) > 0) h--;
            if (g <= h)
            {
                swap(list,g,h);
                g++;
                h--;
            }
        }

        while (g < h);

        if (h > first) quickSort (list,first,h);
        if (g < last) quickSort (list,g,last);      
    }

    private static void swap (ArrayList <String> list, int first, int h)
    {
        String temp = list.get(first);
        list.set(first, list.get(h));
        list.set(h, temp);
    }
```

I works, but it doesn't really make sense to me. Can someone give me an explanation for this code somehow?
Or give a more simple code for the quicksort if possible?

Comment: which part does not make sense to you? which part needs a explanation?

Comment: I suggest working at it by commenting everything you do understand. You should also make sure you understand the concept of quick sort. If there is anything left over that you don't understand you will be able to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Did you read e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort?

Comment: Sorry im not asking precisely, i just got a little frustrated with this. I get the principles of Quicksort, but I just couldn't get this code to make sense or find anything else. Anyways i think it's beginning to make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume you know how quicksort works and are just wondering about this particular implementation. I'm also assuming the code is correct. We begin by defining the range we're working on and choosing a pivot.

```
private static void quickSort (ArrayList <String> list, int first, int last) {

    int g = first; 
    int h = last;

    int midIndex = (first + last) / 2;
    String dividingValue = list.get(midIndex);
```

Then we start at opposite ends of the range and work inwards. We want everything on the left of the pivot to be smaller and everything on the right to be larger. Thus we skip any elements that already satisfy this.

```
    do {
        while (list.get(g).compareTo(dividingValue) < 0) g++;
        while (list.get(h).compareTo(dividingValue) > 0) h--;
```

When we reach two elements that both violate the property we swap them so they're on the correct side and then move on inwards. The `if (g <= h)` check is necessary because we apply `g++` and `h--` blindly (as opposed to checking for value as in the `while` loops) after swapping. It seems that it swaps the pivot to handle not having an opposite element to swap with. This definitely needs to be tested to ensure correctness.

```
        if (g <= h)
        {
            swap(list, g, h);
            g++;
            h--;
        }
```

We continue doing this until we reach the pivot (slightly implicit since the pivot can be swapped).

```
    } while (g < h);
```

We recursively apply this property on subsections of the list so that the entire list gets sorted.

```
    if (h > first) 
        quickSort(list, first, h);
    if (g < last) 
        quickSort(list, g, last);      
}

private static void swap (ArrayList <String> list, int first, int h)
{
    String temp = list.get(first);
    list.set(first, list.get(h));
    list.set(h, temp);
}
```

Comment: +1 ,all details covered !